# How to part hair in blender?

Tags: particles, hair

I'm trying to make a character with long hair, but there's a problem. When I set parting to 1.00 there is a huge bald spot on her head. When I turn it to 0 the bald spot goes away, but I have a bunch of hair strands covering her face. Does anyone know how to part her hair without leaving a bald spot?

[image]

[image]